# How do I avoid infinite recursion when parsing a comparison in form of "expression < expression"

Tags: parsing, bnf, pratt-parser

I want to parse a comparison in the following BNF:

```
expression ::= comparison | number | string | "(" expression ")"
comparison ::= ( expression ( ">" | "<" | ">=" | "<=" | "==" | "!=" ) expression )
```

Because I can't know whether there will be a comparison operator following the expression, I thought of first trying to parse a comparison. This code will call the function for parsing an expression again, which will then result in an infinite loop. How do handle this problem properly?

Comment: Your code should be deciding which non-terminal to parse by looking at one (or more) look-ahead tokens. Also that BNF doesn't look right; the `number` and `string` tokens shouldn't be at the same level as the higher-level non-terminals. The BNF should reflect the operator precedence and logical hierarchy of the expression syntax.

Comment: The problem is that I can't know after how many tokens a token that can decide that will follow. I could apply the "look-ahead" technique until now, but I got stuck here because it won't work in this context.

Comment: Where did that BNF come from?

Comment: From myself, but I got orientation from the Java definition in BNF

Comment: Well generally `comparison` would accept something like a lower-level expression with higher-precedence operators rather than having that left-recursion. An LR parser could deal with that because, well because that's how LR parsers work.

Comment: I don't know how that would work (this is my first try in creating a parser, I'm sorry if I don't understand), because you could have something like: (3 > 2) == (6 < 5).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159761/discussion-between-chrisstar-and-pointy).

Comment: [Here's the Wikipedia article on left-recursive grammars and how to deal with them.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So at the end I solved it by having a function `expression` which calls another function `expression_without_infix`. Then it tests if the next operator is an infix operator and parses it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Douglas Crockford uses a Pratt Parser for JSLint, which can handle nested expressions of unknown depth. He explains the theory behind it in his article [Top Down Operator Precedence](https://www.crockford.com/javascript/tdop/tdop.html). There also appears to be [a Pratt Parser on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pratt-parser) (though I haven't tested it).

Perhaps something like that will be useful?